# How to produce a video with a certain bitrate in dash.js

Tags: javascript, html, mpeg-dash, dash.js

**How to produce a video with a certain bitrate in dash.js**

**I have bitrate 
0 - 248kb
1-  495kb
2 - 742kb
3 - 990kb
4 - 1225kb
5 - 1840kb**

I want open video in 990kb.

I do

```
player.setAutoSwitchQualityFor('video', false);
player.setQualityFor("video", 3);
```

**It is necessary to wait until the old bitrate and the buffer have loaded
how can i change the bitrate without waiting for the buffer ?**

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for dash.js covers all this stuff: http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html

You can set the initial bitrate using `setInitialBitrateFor`: http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#setInitialBitrateFor__anchor

```
player.setAutoSwitchQualityFor('video', false);
player.setInitialBitrateFor("video", 3);
```

You can change bitrate more quickly using `setFastSwitchEnabled` to true: http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/module-MediaPlayer.html#setFastSwitchEnabled__anchor

```
player.setFastSwitchEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thx. But this is no work setFastSwitchEnabled(true); 
player.setInitialBitrateFor('video', 0); don`t change quality

Comment: I need to completely stop the video and run it with the right bitrate